# CASE expression returns wrong value when using CEILING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datatypes, type-conversion

I've run into an issue where a `CASE` expression does not return what I expect.

As a test, I added a *decimal* variable and ran the same `CASE` expression against it and it works fine, returning the results as I would expect (rounding the value up when `IsGun=1`. But when I run that same `CASE` expression against another decimal value, it always returns the value with the `CEILING()` function and never returns the original value.

Here is the SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Num decimal(8,2);
    set @Num = 12.54;
    WITH PQ AS
    ( 
        SELECT 
            UPC, 
            Price1, 
            DBID,
            AVG(Price1) OVER (PARTITION BY UPC) AS Price1Avg
        FROM
            vProducts_PriceQty_Union
    )
    SELECT 
        PQ.UPC,
        PQ.Price1,
        PQ.Price1Avg,
        (CASE WHEN p.IsGun = 1 THEN CEILING(@Num) ELSE @Num END) AS UsingVar,
        CAST(
            (CASE WHEN P.IsGun = 1 THEN CEILING(PQ.Price1Avg) ELSE PQ.Price1 END)
             AS NUMERIC(8,2))
        AS PriceAdj,
        PQ.DBID,
        P.IsGun
    FROM
        PQ
     INNER JOIN
        products P ON PQ.UPC = P.UPC
```

Here is a snippet of the results:

```
UPC             Price1      Price1Avg   UsingVar    PriceAdj    DBID  IsGun
942000899195    14.9900     14.990000   12.54       15.00       1       0
980420671300    29.9900     29.990000   12.54       30.00       1       0
980420671310    29.9900     29.990000   12.54       30.00       1       0
980426713020    29.9900     29.990000   12.54       30.00       1       0
980426713120    29.9900     29.990000   12.54       30.00       1       0
000998622130    319.0000    319.000000  13.00       319.00      1       1
000998624730    314.0000    314.000000  13.00       314.00      1       1
000998624970    419.0000    419.000000  13.00       419.00      1       1
008244284754    1015.0000   1015.000000 13.00       1015.00     2       1
010633012288    267.0000    267.000000  13.00       267.00      6       1
```

And here is the data it comes from *vProducts_PriceQty_Union*:

```
UPC             Price1  Price2  Quantity    DBID
942000899195    14.9900 0.0000  2.00        1
980420671300    29.9900 0.0000  3.00        1
980420671310    29.9900 0.0000  1.00        1
980426713020    29.9900 0.0000  2.00        1
980426713120    29.9900 0.0000  1.00        1
```

As you can see from the first five, where *IsGun* = 0, the first `CASE` expression using the fixed variable returns the *UsingVar* value as what we would expect, 12.54. And for the last five, it also returns the value we would expect, 13.

But in the second `CASE` expression (exactly the same logic), the *PriceAdj* uses the `CEILING` function on every single one of them, regardless of whether *IsGun* = 1 or not.

Why isn't the query returning the expected results?

In some of the tables used for the union view the data types for *Price1* and *Price2* were *smallmoney* and *decimal(8,2)*. I have since changed them all to be *decimal(8,2)*, but that did not affect the results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To reproduce the problem:

```
SELECT *, (CASE
    WHEN IsGun=1 THEN CEILING(Price1Avg)
    ELSE Price1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT UPC, IsGun, Price1,
           AVG(CAST(Price1 AS numeric(8, 2))) OVER (PARTITION BY UPC) AS Price1Avg
    FROM (
        VALUES ('A', 0, 14.99),
               ('B', 0, 29.99),
               ('C', 1, 319.00),
               ('D', 1, 314.00)
        ) AS x(UPC, IsGun, Price1)
    ) AS sub;
```

What happens here is that `CEILING(PQ.Price1Avg)` produces a `numeric(38, 0)`.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx), the output type of `CEILING()` is of the same base datatype as the input, although the scale (the number of decimals) may change, which is what happens here.

- The `AVG()` function, in my tests, returns `numeric(38, 6)`.
- The `CEILING()` function on that column, however, outputs `numeric(38, 0)`:

To verify:

```
SELECT CEILING(CAST(123.45 AS numeric(38, 6)))
```

As a workaround, you could explicitly convert the output of the `CEILING()` function, which should give you the correct results:

```
SELECT *, (CASE
    WHEN IsGun=1 THEN CAST(CEILING(Price1Avg) AS numeric(8, 2)) -- Explicit CAST.
    ELSE Price1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT UPC, IsGun, Price1,
           AVG(CAST(Price1 AS numeric(8, 2))) OVER (PARTITION BY UPC) AS Price1Avg
    FROM (
        VALUES ('A', 0, 14.99),
               ('B', 0, 29.99),
               ('C', 1, 319.00),
               ('D', 1, 314.00)
        ) AS x(UPC, IsGun, Price1)
    ) AS sub;
```

Comment: Should also note that case statements cannot return multiple different types, but an IIF expression can, so that may be advisable.

Comment: @AdamMartin that isn't correct. An `iif` gets expanded out to `case`. It [returns the type with the greatest data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx) from the two options. It isn't possible for any expression to return data type X in one row and data type Y in another row for the same column.

Comment: @Daniel, most helpful. As soon as I CAST(x AS NUMERIC(8,2)) for each output, it returned the result I was looking for. Many thanks to you and this community!